# VBA: Efficient way to build up a table without duplicates

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I need to read a file containing several entries and build up a table which contains a summary of the file. In the read file, multiple entries of one value are possible, in the summary only single entries are wanted, and they must be sorted.

I've implemented two methods:

1. I used a loop to check if the output table already contains the value, if not add it. The loop was iterating through the whole list (unsorted)
2. "Optimization" of 1.: After each insertion of a new value the table is beeing sorted and the loop is beeing aborted when a value was found.

Both methods did their job, but took a very long time. Is there any more efficient way to do this?

**edit**

for a better understanding: My file looks like this

```
a
d
b
c
a
```

and my list/table should look like:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague but you could use a Collection or Dictionary to test if a value has already been found.

Comment: Would http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819 with SELECT DISTINCT suit?

Comment: assylias: I added an example, I hope this will help understanding. Remou: The ADO solution looks nice, but for better compatibility I'd like to do this just in standard excel vba.

Comment: Is it a text file?  Could you use the DOS Sort command before reading it?  Could you read it into a worksheet and sort it there?

Comment: yes, it's a text file. the problem is, that each line is not started by the value but by a timestamp which is important to keep the sorting like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example that uses a Dictionary:

```
Sub test()

  Dim a As Variant
  Dim dict As Variant
  Dim i As Long

  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  ReDim a(1 To 4) As Variant

  a(1) = "a"
  a(2) = "b"
  a(3) = "c"
  a(4) = "a"
  For i = 1 To 4
    If Not dict.exists(a(i)) Then dict.Add a(i), i
  Next i

  MsgBox "array size = " & UBound(a, 1) & " and dict size = " & dict.Count 'respectively 4 and 3

End Sub
```

Comment: Also, if you put the data in a sheet and loop over the cells, that could be a significant factor in the overall performance but you don't specificy how you read the data.

Comment: I am going to figure it out, how using an array instead of iterating through the cells impacts the efficiency of my algo

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Excel 2010 there is built in functionality to remove duplicates.

I would import all the data from your files and then remove the duplicates.

From the UI, select your data and then click on the **Data** tab and **Remove duplicates**.  When prompted, select the options you want and then click on OK.

The same functionality is available from VBA.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates()
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$500").RemoveDuplicates _
    Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

In Excel 2003 and earlier, this VBA could be used.  It uses the built in advanced filter functionality.

```
Sub Remove_Duplicates_2003()

    Range("A1:B500").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
     CopyToRange:=Range("C1"), Unique:=True

    Columns("A:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I use Excel 2003. The code snippet you posted looks great, but is not working in 2003. The Object "Range" has no such method. Is there a similar efficient workaround?

Comment: The functionality that the code uses only exists in Excel 2010.  I have added code that should work for Excel 2003 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Are you strictly wanting to use VBA?  Well, I supposed this idea can be recorded into a macro...

I would highlight the column of duplicating values, then do a **Filter > Advanced Filter > Copy to another location > [x] Unique values only**.

Then Sort the resulting table of unique values it gives you.